# Can I resubmit my accepted paper after I withdraw it from the same journal?

Tags: phd, thesis

I have withdrawn my paper after it was accepted for financial reasons.

Can I resubmit it to the same journal ?

Comment: Have you checked to see if this has been asked already?

Comment: yes I checked and I don't found it

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't submit to a journal that does not charge authors? They usually come with the upside of being better quality.

Comment: @CapeCode depends what you mean by "charge authors". Many highly-respected open access journals charge APCs.

Comment: @Flyto I mean what it means: “ask authors for money in exchange for publishing the paper”.

Comment: @CapeCode well then, there are plenty of high-quality open access journals that do that.

Comment: @Flyto and there are journals of similar and often better quality that don’t. Just submit to those.

Comment: @CapeCode the OP presumably had a reason for submitting to the journal they did, and a reason for wanting to resubmit there. We don't know the choices in their field. I was simply objecting to your suggestion that journals that don't charge "usually come with the upside of being better quality". Maybe they are in your field.

Comment: @Flyto regardless of the field, when a journal gets money for accepting papers it will accept more papers than it should.

Comment: @CapeCode [citation needed]. I don't want to get into the whole open access debate here, but in case you're not aware, that's one of the usual bits of FUD that publishers put around to try to discredit open access.

Comment: @Flyto nonsense. what publisher wants to “discredit open access”? It’s a goldmine for them: infinite papers, money for papers nobody will ever read, all that research money going into publishing instead. All of this being advocated for free. Have you bought RELX stocks yet? You should.

Comment: @Flyto you make it sound like publishers don't like open access. That's completely untrue. Open access is great for publishers because 1) it's guaranteed revenue, i.e. you don't need to convince people to subscribe and 2) you barely have to do anything you aren't already doing. Take a look around, there are very few publishers that don't offer open access if the authors want it, and it's not because it's less profitable for them. The pure-OA publisher Hindawi has higher profit margins than Elsevier - that should say something.

Answer (score 17):

That depends entirely on the journal itself. If the submission process is automated, you could just try and see what happens. But you could, and probably should, contact the editor for information, explaining the earlier withdrawal and why that isn't an issue at present.

But, I assume some journals wouldn't like to reconsider it. And take care that it isn't a predatory journal. They might want to accept it again, but you may have better options elsewhere.

Answer (score 14):

Journals and editors want to accept and publish your manuscripts. If it has already been reviewed and accepted, that is even more reason for them to publish it. They need citations and a better reputation as much as you do.

If you are unable to pay fees (such as open access fees) at the moment, you should contact the editor if you still wish to publish with them in the future. You do not want to wait for reviews again if it can be helped. Even if the new reviewers approve of the manuscript as well, this is a time consuming process for everyone. It is better to come to some arrangement with the editor or at least notify them in case an automated system rejects your resubmission.

The exact process will vary between journals. Only an editor will know the policy for a specific journal. They will want to help you. Don’t hesitate to contact them about questions of this nature: it is their job to handle these matters.

Comment: Indeed. Most (non-predatory) journals that have page charges also have ways to request that the charges be waived based on financial situations. That should have been the route for the OP to begin with.

Comment: *they want citations* also they want your money.

Comment: That is true, there are many exemption policies for publishing fees. If you are from a developing nation or don’t have an affiliation (e.g., jobhunting), it is worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you know what you're doing before resubmitting**.

If you submitted to an open access journal, then it's nonsense to resubmit because it will just lead to them charging you the submission fee again. If you submitted to a hybrid journal, then you shouldn't have withdrawn it in the first place because you can simply decline open access. If you needed a discount or a waiver, you could've negotiated for it without withdrawing.

In a nutshell, if you withdrew the paper because of financial reasons, and this was the right decision on your part, I can't see why you would want to resubmit to the same journal *unless you've found funding to pay for open access*. If this is indeed the case, then just write to the editor saying so, and do whatever she says.